# pyinstaller not outputting .app

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller

I am running the command `pyinstaller --onefile --windowed /myapp.py`. According to the docs, this should output executables for windows as well as .app for MacOS. However, I am only getting one output and not the .app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't make this obvious from the website, but [from the docs](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#id34):

> If you need to distribute your application for more than one OS, for
>   example both Windows and Mac OS X, you must install PyInstaller on
>   each platform and bundle your app separately on each.

So you'll need to package it on a Mac, sorry.